# Hive - most efficient way to check for duplicates on one partition against large table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, data-quality

I'm creating a query to run on a very large Hive table (millions of rows inserted every day).

I need to check (after the rows have been added, not before) for duplicates. I was wondering whether the below is the most efficient way of doing it, or whether I should be just be checking the newly inserted rows for duplicates against the existing data. Could this be done with an OVER clause, for example? Or would there be no efficiency gain?

Table is partitioned on load date and I use tez.

```
select 
col1, 
count(*) as col1_count 
from database.table
group by col1
having count(*) >=2;
```

Comment: Just some questions to clarify: Do you only need to check whether the value of col1 is duplicated (no need to test the whole row). Also, do you just need to check, or do you also need to do something afterwards? (otherwise you may want to look at efficiency of the whole process). And can you identifiy rows that were added today? -- Finally: there are several theoretical answers, but the only true answer for you will be found by trying out a few options.

Comment: Yes, just col1 rather than the whole row. I just need to monitor, so all I'm doing is outputting a count.  I'm not cleansing. I can find rows that were added today from the partition column which is a date stored as a string.  I also have a load timestamp for every row that is a true timestamp.